# Redirect to a page based on user roles in codeigniter

Tags: authentication, codeigniter

Am working on a user login authentication with codeigniter.

The login script works great. My question is, when a user is logged in I want the user to be redirected to a page based on his user roles

Roles are as below **subscriber**, **admin**, **client**, **postman**

**User_model.php** is as below

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public $status;
    public $roles;

    function __construct(){
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->status = $this->config->item('status');
        $this->roles = $this->config->item('roles');
    }

    public function insertUser($d)
    {
            $string = array(
                'firstname'=>$d['firstname'],
                'lastname'=>$d['lastname'],
                'phonenumber'=>$d['phonenumber'],
                'email'=>$d['email'],
                'roles'=>$this->roles[1],
                'status'=>$this->status[1],
                'password'=> '',
                'last_login'=> '',
                'created_at'=> '',
                'updated_at'=> ''
            );
            $q = $this->db->insert_string('users',$string);
            $this->db->query($q);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function isDuplicate($email)
    {
        $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email), 1);
        return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    public function insertToken($user_id)
    {
        $token = substr(sha1(rand()), 0, 30);
        $date = date('Y-m-d');

        $string = array(
                'token'=> $token,
                'user_id'=>$user_id,
                'created'=>$date
            );
        $query = $this->db->insert_string('tokens',$string);
        $this->db->query($query);
        return $token . $user_id;

    }

    public function isTokenValid($token)
    {
       $tkn = substr($token,0,30);
       $uid = substr($token,30);

        $q = $this->db->get_where('tokens', array(
            'tokens.token' => $tkn,
            'tokens.user_id' => $uid), 1);

        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            $row = $q->row();

            $created = $row->created;
            $createdTS = strtotime($created);
            $today = date('Y-m-d');
            $todayTS = strtotime($today);

            if($createdTS != $todayTS){
                return false;
            }

            $user_info = $this->getUserInfo($row->user_id);
            return $user_info;

        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function getUserInfo($id)
    {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            $row = $q->row();
            return $row;
        }else{
            error_log('no user found getUserInfo('.$id.')');
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function updateUserInfo($post)
    {
        $data = array(
               'password' => $post['password'],
               'last_login' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s A'),
               'created_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s A'),
               'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s A'),
               'status' => $this->status[1]
            );
        $this->db->where('id', $post['user_id']);
        $this->db->update('users', $data);
        $success = $this->db->affected_rows();

        if(!$success){
            error_log('Unable to updateUserInfo('.$post['user_id'].')');
            return false;
        }

        $user_info = $this->getUserInfo($post['user_id']);
        return $user_info;
    }

    public function checkLogin($post)
    {
        $this->load->library('password');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('email', $post['email']);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $userInfo = $query->row();

        if(!$this->password->validate_password($post['password'], $userInfo->password)){
            error_log('Unsuccessful login attempt('.$post['email'].')');
            return false;
        }

        $this->updateLoginTime($userInfo->id);

        unset($userInfo->password);
        return $userInfo;
    }

}
```

The main code for controller is as seen below

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

        public $status;
        public $roles;

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('User_model', 'user_model', TRUE);
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
            $this->status = $this->config->item('status');
            $this->roles = $this->config->item('roles');
        }

    public function index()
    {

            if(empty($this->session->userdata['email'])){
                redirect(site_url().'main/login/');
            }

            /*front page*/
            $data = $this->session->userdata;
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('index', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');
    }



        public function login()
        {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('login');
                $this->load->view('footer');
            }else{

                $post = $this->input->post();
                $clean = $this->security->xss_clean($post);

                $userInfo = $this->user_model->checkLogin($clean);

                if(!$userInfo){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'The login was unsucessful');
                    redirect(site_url().'main/login');
                }
                foreach($userInfo as $key=>$val){
                    $this->session->set_userdata($key, $val);
                }
                redirect(site_url().'main/');
            }

        }


        public function logout()
        {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect(site_url().'main/login/');
        }


}
```

Comment: post checkLogin model as well as the relevant data it returns (example array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may be off because it requires some assumptions.

The Assumptions:

1. There is only one "role" per user
2. The value of `$userInfo->role` is a string
3. The controller you want to send the authorized user to is `main`
4. The methods of the `main` controller are named the same as the "role" e.g.
   'subscriber', 'admin', 'client', 'postman'

If any of the above is false then this answer won't work.

Here's my suggested solution. I'll make comments about it after this code.

```
public function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        //$clean = $this->security->xss_clean($post);

        $userInfo = $this->user_model->checkLogin($post);

        if( ! $userInfo)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'The login was unsucessful');
            redirect('main/login');
        }

        $this->session->set_userdata($userInfo);
        redirect('main/'.$userInfo->roles);
    }

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('login');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

You're probably wondering why I rearranged everything. Well, mostly because it eliminates the need for an `else` to go with the `if`. Less code is good - right?

A call to `redirect()` *ends script execution* meaning that any code after a `redirect` won't run. Because the `if($this->form_validation->run()){` code block ends with a call to `redirect` that's where this function ends. So, you don't need an `else`. Should validation fail execution go straight to the view loading code.

Your syntax for `redirect` is wrong. `redirect()` will build the URL based on your config file values. ([docs here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect)) So, make sure `$config['base_url']` is set correctly.

Your code

```
redirect(site_url().'main/');
```

should be written

```
redirect('main/');
```

You probably noticed that I commented out the line

```
$clean = $this->security->xss_clean($post);
```

Most developers will argue that XSS prevention should be done on output, not on input. (More than you want to know about XSS prevention [HERE](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).)

Since the input data is being used to select a DB record, it appears the values are escaped, and you're not storing the inputs there is no danger. Using `xss_clean()` is resource intensive and not useful in this case.

I removed the following loop

```
foreach ($userInfo as $key => $val)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata($key, $val);
}
```

and changed it to

```
$this->session->set_userdata($userInfo);
```

If you look at the code for `set_userdata()` and you will find it pretty much uses the exact same code you created. (The code is in `/system/core/Session/Session.php` around line 785.) Stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and use the framework's toolset. `set_userdata()` will accept an associative array and do what you need to be done.

Because the value of `$userInfo->roles` is a string that matches the name of the method you want to redirect them to this call should do the trick.

```
redirect('main/'.$userInfo->roles);
```

If `main` isn't the right controller then change it above. If the method names don't match the role values then additional code will be needed.

Hope this is clear and is helpful.

Comment: Tried your code, didn't work - Made some edits in the question (added **controller** and **model** code

Comment: What is the structure of `$config['roles']`? Is it  `array('Subscriber'=>0, 'admin'=>1, 'client'=>2, 'postman'=>3)` or is it `array('Subscriber', 'admin', 'client', 'postman')`?

Comment: In the model you call `$this->roles = $this->config->item('roles');` That's the `$config` I am asking about.

Comment: True my bad it is like this `$config['roles'] = array('subscriber', 'admin', 'client', 'postman');`

Comment: Worked out well. Thanks alot.

Comment: I know i should have set a new thread for this. How to prevent user from access those pages if not logged in, because currently if i accessed `main/subscriber` am able to view page when not logged in I have created a function `public function subscriber() {

        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/subscriber', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
        }` in Main controller. How do I also pass the user data e.g username, firstname, lastname to `redirect('main/'.$userInfo->roles);` pages.

Comment: You have all that user data in session data. It should still be there after the redirect.