# How to prevent user from accessing certain pages if not logged in in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3

Currently if i accessed main/subscriber am able to view page when not logged in I have created a function in Main controller -refer to [User role page redirect codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53142772/redirect-to-a-page-based-on-user-roles-in-codeigniter/53145103) for clarity on code.

```
public function subscriber() {

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('dashboard/subscriber', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Comment: How will you pass the data when the user is not logged in, as per your question?

Comment: Your topic and the description say two different requirements. Let lnow what exactly you need?

Comment: Was hoping to shoot two birds with one stone. Maybe I wasn't clear,  I am able to login and go to user role page. However, even when am not logged and I go to URL xxx/main/subscriber, am still able to view that page which I believe is not right.

Comment: @DanielOmara check my answer given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to protect your pages. Let's assume that your `$_SESSION['email']` variable is only set when the user has logged in. We can use that as a flag to determine if the user is logged in.

Add these functions to your `User_model` (make sure the model is autoloaded).

```
public function is_logged() {
     if (is_null($this->session->userdata('email')) {
         redirect('main/login');
         exit; // just in case
     }
}

public function is_allowed($perm) {
     $roles = $this->session->userdata('roles');
     if ($roles !== 'admin' && $perm !== $roles) {
         // maybe set flashdata so user knows why they were redirected
         redirect('main/' . $roles);
         exit; // just in case
     }
}
```

Then controller:

```
class Subscriber extends CI_Controller {

    public function construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->user_model->is_logged(); // can merge with below func, just make sure it is called first (!imp)
        $this->user_model->is_allowed('subscriber');
    }

    public function subscriber() {
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/subscriber', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

This is as basic as it gets. You can do it more fancy if you wish. I personally use a database-based ACL system.

Also consider renaming `roles` to just `role` in your db and elsewhere, it is confusing considering a user only has 1 role (given your previous question).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to protect your different routes based on user is logged in or not, use a session variable.
when a user logged in in your app then set a sessio variable like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in', TRUE);
```

and check that variable in constructor of a controller so that user is verified before calling any method.

```
class Demo_controller extends CI_Controller{
 public function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   // check if user is logged in
   if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
     // user is not logged in then redirect user to any page you want
   }
 }
}
```

you can also use hooks for creating such system in Codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent user from accessing certain pages if not logged in codeigniter,

you should first `set_userdata` when login.

Change the **controller** as below. When session data are not empty it will redirect you to the specific page. Otherwise, 'write what needs to be done'.

```
public function subscriber()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('id')!="")
        {
            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard/subscriber', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');

        } else {
            //your code here
        }           
    }
```